# Disable Touchscreen Automatically on Boot in Bash

Tags: touchscreen, xinput, hp-spectre

I have a touchscreen laptop that uses Ubuntu (HP Spectre X360). My screen has been replaced a couple of times and so there is a sometimes a problem with the touchscreen that makes it think that it is being touched randomly all over the screen. This makes it impossible to control anything and a reboot is required.

I know how to disable the touchscreen:

In the terminal I type `xinput` and I am presented with a list, e.g.:

[image]

I then find the number that corresponds to the `ELAN Touchscreen` (in this case 10) and then type:

`xinput disable 10`

Once the screen is going haywire however, it is too late to do this, as I can't type anything. So I want to automate this to be typed as soon as I boot my computer and disable the touchscreen automatically every time. But sometimes the number is not 10, it is sometimes 9.

I suppose I need some simple bash screen that inputs `xinput` but then finds the number that corresponds to the touchscreen and inputs `xinput disable #`.

Could anyone help me with that please?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278333/how-can-i-permanently-disable-a-xinput-device

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to improve [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278333/how-can-i-permanently-disable-a-xinput-device) for you a little.

Create a file called for example `disable-touchscreen.sh` in the `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/` folder with the following content.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
[ -x /usr/bin/xinput ] && /usr/bin/xinput disable 'ELAN Touchscreen'
```

Make sure it is executable (`chmod +x /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/disable-touchscreen.sh`).

You can use it this way, quoting `man xinput`:

> device can be the device name as a string or the XID of the device.

If your distribution doesn't contain the `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/` folder (Ubuntu most likely doesn't), then create it.

Also take a look into your home, if there is a file named `.xinitrc`, ensure it contains a block like

```sh
# run all system xinitrc shell scripts.
for file in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/* ; do
        . $file
done
```

Comment: I'm in the folder `/etc/X11/xinit/` but there is no `xinitrc.d` folder. There is a file called `xinitrc` however. Should I create a `xinitrc.d` folder?

Answer (score 0):

To permanently disable the touchscreen input, here is another method:

- Edit the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf`
- Find the entry for the ELAN Touchscreen
- In "Driver" section, Change "evdev" to "libinput" so it would look like this:

  ```
    Driver "libinput"
  ```

  If you find in the file an entry for "Touchscreen catchall", add to it the line:

  ```
    Option "Ignore" "on"
  ```

  Another possibility is if you find this line: `MatchIsTouchscreen "on"`,
  then change it to `MatchIsTouchscreen "off"`.
- Save the file and reboot.

---

Another method uses the command:

```
xinput --set-prop 'name of touchpad device' 'Device Enabled' 0
```

Comment: For me, there was no ELAN Touchscreen, but there was the identifier: evdev touchscreen catchall. So I did as you suggested but the Touchscreen still worked when I rebooted unfortunately.

Comment: I have added more.

Comment: I have just added Option "Ignore" "on" and changed to MatchIsTouchscreen "off" and now when I log in, neither my mouse or my keyboard work (once I log in) and so I am unable to undo what I did. Please advise asap as I am no longer able use my machine.

Comment: It might have been added at the wrong location. You might need to use a live boot to undo.

Comment: Please see https://superuser.com/questions/1576422/mouse-and-keyboard-disabled-accidentally for a screenshot of what I changed the values to.

Comment: It might have been enough to do `MatchIsTouchscreen`.

Comment: The keyboard and mouse work before I enter the password and log into my account. Is there no way I can fix this without a live boot? I don't have a boot data stick currently.

Comment: You might be able to edit the file in the browser. See for example
[How to Edit Source Files Directly in Chrome](https://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/) that uses Developer Tools to load, edit and save the file.

Comment: I can't do it this way unfortunately. I guess I will have to wait until I can get a live boot data stick. Will I be able to plug a USB keyboard in and use that?

Comment: No reason that this wouldn't work.

Comment: I have to navigate to the file using the touchscreen and it's almost impossible to do it with the touchscreen only partially working.

Comment: Okay I managed to navigate to usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ but there is no 10-evdev.conf file available to select. So you cannot access it this way.

Comment: Don't you remember which file you updated?

Comment: Yes. I have said above, it was 10-evdev.conf

Comment: Anyway, I have managed to get my mouse and keyboard working again - I have posted my solution on https://superuser.com/questions/1576422/mouse-and-keyboard-disabled-accidentally. I still have no solution for the touchscreen, but I think it is safer just to leave it alone.

Comment: Now that you have a way of undoing it, why not experiment.

Answer (score 0):

for disable the touchpad im my linux I added one line
"Option "Ignore" "on""
to the file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf

and now the section looks like this:

Section "InputClass"
Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
MatchIsTouchpad "on"
Option "Ignore" "on"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Driver "libinput"
EndSection

and it works fine for me without xorg