# Mouse and keyboard disabled accidentally

Tags: keyboard, mouse, ubuntu-18.04

I posted this question

[Disable Touchscreen Automatically on Boot in Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1574600/disable-touchscreen-automatically-on-boot-in-bash)

Hoping to disable my touchscreen. I followed the answer that begins "to permanently disable the touchscreen input". Now, once I log into my ubuntu account, my mouse and my keyboard no longer work.

Because of this, I can't get back into the file to undo what I changed.

Is there a way I can log in without these things being disabled?

The touchscreen is still working but I can't type anything. Nor can I copy paste into the terminal.

---

Using copy and paste in my browser, I have been able to navigate to the file in my browser and take a photo of it:

[image]

It's the bottom section that I edited.

Answer (score 0):

If your Touch is working fine then, just open the file with **GEDIT** and use **on screen keyboard** to change your settings.

Comment: Unfortunately, the on-screen keyboard is working fine EXCEPT for about 3 letters for some reason. So I can't actually type the name of the file I need to open. And I can't copy and paste apparently because I need "ctrl" which the on-screen keyboard doesn't have.

Comment: Take another PC or ask your friend for making a Linux live USB, Boot the live USB in your system and change the file and reboot your system and Boot with System OS.

Answer (score 0):

On the log in screen I can choose `Ubuntu`, `Ubuntu on Wayland` or `Unity`. I tried logging in on `Ubuntu on Wayland` and for some reason, my keyboard and mouse work on this. Them I was able to change the file back and everything is as normal again.